# discord.py | Add role to specific user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to create a command that assigns a role to a user - e.g. `!role [role] [User]`

I searched the internet for hours, but only found commands that give the author of the message a role.
Here's my code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def role(ctx, role):
    member = #What must I write here?
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send("You have not specified a role")
    else:
        test = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=role)
        await discord.Member.add_roles(member, test)
        await ctx.send("Role added")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this -

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Usage - `!role [Member] [Role]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rol(ctx, role, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=role)
    member.add_role(role)
    await ctx.send("role added")
```